# Check if a file contains a string by "grep -q" in JNI

Tags: android, android-ndk, grep, java-native-interface, command

I am writing a small Android program that can check how many files contains a certain string without reading completely their contents
Therefore, I've found a good way to do it is using `grep -q` command. Because of executing the command doesn't output but a exit code (0 : match, 1 : not match)

However I have no idea that how to get the exit code after executing the command completed by C language in JNI.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/478898/how-to-execute-a-command-and-get-output-of-command-within-c

Comment: Thanks Blackbelt for your reference. In my case, execute "grep -q" is without output. It can only checked if completed by the exit code
echo $?
Do you have any idea else?

Comment: All -q does is suppress the normal output of grep. Just don't use that option, and use the technique described in the given link.

Comment: I decided to use -q due to I don't want to read the whole files which are mostly large.